# Jetpack Compose: Close button outside of dialog modal

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to create a dialog modal where a close button is located just outside the actual dialog, like so:

[image]

Does this go against Material Design standards-and would mean I have a case to revise UI design of the dialog? If not, is there a straightforward way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AlertDialog` [variant](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#AlertDialog(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function0)) with the `content` parameter and use a `Column` with `Transparent` background where you can add the `Button` and the AlertDialog content.

Something like:

```
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    if (openDialog.value) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = {
                openDialog.value = false
            }
        ) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Transparent)) {

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End).padding(bottom = 10.dp),
                    onClick = {openDialog.value = false},
                ) {
                    Text("Close")
                }

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight(),
                    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large
                ) {
                  //AlertDialog content                            
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

[image]